# Associating a Twilio number with a specific Frontline user

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-frontline

I'm trying to figure out how to associate a specific user with a Twilio number, so that when a call/text comes to that number it only goes to that user's Frontline app/account.

I'm writing the callbacks in Node.js, and I guess that I'm a bit confused to as to how to identify the target number (as the quickstart I'm using is more focused on the `customerNumber` and relationship with a specific `worker`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set up [Custom Routing](https://www.twilio.com/docs/frontline/handle-incoming-conversations#2-custom-routing) for this and, instead of using the customer number (the `MessageBinding.Address` from the webhook parameters) to do the routing as in the quick start, you can use the number the customer sent the message to, which I think is the `MessageBinding.ProxyAddress`.

Check out all [the parameters that are sent to the `onConversationRoute` webhook URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/frontline/handle-incoming-conversations#onconversationroute). You might also want to test and just log out all the available parameters in order to match to the target number.

Comment: I've seen this, but I actually haven't been able to figure out how to access the `onConversationRoute` webhook. I'm not able to access the Voice in Frontline TwiML, it wasn't automatically created. Because of this (I think), the `event` is returning null on the `routing` callback.

Answer (score -1):

The best and the only option I see the Call Forwarding for that purpose and using Twilio's inbuilt TwiML Bins.

Complete info:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding

Comment: I'm not trying to do call forwarding, though, I'm trying to figure out how to associate the worker's specific Frontline app with this specific number. Which is why I thought it would be done a similar way to the custom routing callbacks, which decides which worker is going to receive this message/call.